# Error putting Instant Rails on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get my Instant Rails working on my Windows 7 laptop.

The error I keep getting when trying to access my site files are:

```
c:/rails/ruby/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in 'report_activate_error'
RubyGem version error: rack<1.1.0 not~> 1.0.1> <Gem::LoadError>
from c:/rails/ruby/lib/ruby.site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in  'activate'
from c:/rails/ruby/lib/ruby.site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in 'gem'
from c:/depot/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb:34
from c://rails/ruby/lib/ruby.site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31 in 'gem_original_require'
etc...
```

I have intalled Rubygems 1.3.7 and they work fine and when I run the test it works and the gem env shows that the 1.3.7 has been installed correctly.

What can I do to get this working?

Any prompt help would be VERY appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your `rack` gem is outdated. Try to run `gem update rack`. Or, if you use Rails with Bundler, just run `bundle install` in the root of your project and it will do everything for you.</s>

I decided to write a little manual about the Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails stable installation.

1. Download RubyInstaller 1.8.7 [from here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/71492/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p299.exe). During the installation, check the 'Add Ruby executables to your PATH' box. After the installation, don't forget to restard `cmd`. Then try running `ruby -v` and `gem -v` to check for installed Ruby 1.8.7 and RubyGems 1.3.7;
2. Install the latest stable Rails 2.3.8 using `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`; Check it using `rails -v`;
3. Create a new application using `rails myapp`;
4. Test it: `script/server`. That's it!

Comment: Thanks for that. I run gem update rack and it says nothing to update

Comment: Hi again, also with bundle install it says bundle is not a recognised internal or external command.

Comment: Which version of Rails do you use? Is there a `Gemfile` file in your project root? Try also running `gem list` and check for the version of `rake` you've got.

Comment: The versions of Rake I have are: 0.8.7, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.3

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault. I meant the `rack` version. And do you have another Ruby installation on your machine?

Comment: I've added a quick guide about installation of Ruby + Rails on Windows 7 and tested it. Try!

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask them via Twitter. ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks it all works until the last part when I run the app and I still get the same initial error. So rails and ruby all are fine as is java etc
maybe my app file is corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

gem install rack -v 1.0.1